# Как сохранить сессию клиента?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Сайт чат. Как сделать так, чтобы не приходилось с каждым открытием заново перелогиниваться?

Comment: Через cookies, пусть пользователь хранит в них ИД сессии.

Comment: В asp.net сессия и аутентификация - это разные вещи. Вам нужно сделать так, чтобы пользователь оставался аутентифицированным после рестарта браузера. Как это сделать - зависти от того,  как пользователь у вас логинится. Если через имя и пароль - то факт логика скорее всего сохраняется в cookie,  и вам нужно в коде установки cookie указать,  что это должен быть persistent cookie - переживающий рестарт браузера. Попробуйте поискать соответствующий флаг в обработке логина, или просто приведите код действия login - кто-нибудь подскажет,  что надо дописать.